# Android Getting Error While Parseing The XML - At line 1, Column 0 - no element found

Tags: android, xml, parsing, saxparser

Problem is The Error above mentioned

my xml which i am getting from web

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
       <Doc>
       <Root>
       <Record>
               <sar_id>1</sar_id>
               <sar_region><![CDATA[Antigua & Barbuda]]></sar_region>
               <sar_auth>Antigua and Barbuda Defence Force Coast Guards
       </sar_auth>
               <email>abdfcg@candw.ag</email>
               <primary><![CDATA[1 268 462 06 71]]></primary>
               <secondary></secondary>
       </Record>
       <Record>
               <sar_id>2</sar_id>
               <sar_region><![CDATA[Argentina]]></sar_region>
               <sar_auth>Comando de Operaciones Navals, Argentine Navy
       </sar_auth>
               <email>coopacsm@ara.mil.ar</email>
               <primary><![CDATA[54 2932 487 640?]]></primary>
               <secondary></secondary>
       </Record>
       <Record>
               <sar_id>3</sar_id>
               <sar_region><![CDATA[Aruba]]></sar_region>
               <sar_auth>SARFA
       </sar_auth>
               <email>sarfa16@hotmail.com</email>
               <primary><![CDATA[297 5 837371]]></primary>
               <secondary></secondary>
       </Record>
  </Root>
  </Doc>
```

my code to parse xml

```
        try{
    URL url = new URL(
            "http://myurl.com");
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxparser = factory.newSAXParser();

    XMLReader xmlReader = saxparser.getXMLReader();
    SARParser getTParser = new SARParser(itemList);
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(getTParser);


    InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
    is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is.getByteStream()));
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        Log.i("Line", line);
    }
    xmlReader.parse(is);

               //xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```

//ON GOOGLE I FOUND THIS SOLUTION BUT THIS GIVE ME ERROR FOR NOT WELL FORMED TOKEN AT LINE 15

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and log is

```
    09-01 12:32:11.461: WARN/System.err(870): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
09-01 12:32:11.492: WARN/System.err(870):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.finish(ExpatParser.java:538)
09-01 12:32:11.492: WARN/System.err(870):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:468)
09-01 12:32:11.492: WARN/System.err(870):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:329)
09-01 12:32:11.492: WARN/System.err(870):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:286)
09-01 12:32:11.492: WARN/System.err(870):     at com.openxcell.sar.Profile.onCreate(Profile.java:77)
09-01 12:32:11.492: WARN/System.err(870):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
09-01 12:32:11.492: WARN/System.err(870):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
09-01 12:32:11.492: WARN/System.err(870):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
09-01 12:32:11.492: WARN/System.err(870):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
09-01 12:32:11.492: WARN/System.err(870):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
09-01 12:32:11.492: WARN/System.err(870):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 12:32:11.521: WARN/System.err(870):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-01 12:32:11.521: WARN/System.err(870):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
09-01 12:32:11.521: WARN/System.err(870):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 12:32:11.521: WARN/System.err(870):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-01 12:32:11.521: WARN/System.err(870):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
09-01 12:32:11.521: WARN/System.err(870):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
09-01 12:32:11.521: WARN/System.err(870):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me in this.
If you ever had the same problem, what have you tried to resolve...please share ur tricks with me..

Thank You,
Mayur Parekh

Comment: Your error is Line 77 of your Profile class.

Comment: @ Blundell yes you are right the error comes from that line..cause that line is "xmlReader.parse(is);" so this is going to parse that above xml and then it returns xml parseing error!

Comment: Line 1 column 0 means it hasn't read an XML file, so I would check it downloaded correctly / your pointed at an XML file. Have you tried commenting out the BufferedReader & while loop, as it looks like your reading the InputStream twice which is a no no.

Comment: @Blundell actually the BufferedReader i used to just check how data is coming and its all ok..means xml file is downloaded correctly

Comment: Yes so as I said, remove the BufferedReader because it is reading the input stream and you can only read an input stream once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your reading your inputstream twice.

```
 InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
```

This:

```
 new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is.getByteStream()));
```

and

```
  xmlReader.parse(is);
```

both read the InputStream, that is a no no.

Remove the BufferedReader and the while loop (they were only there to confirm the XML had downloaded anyway **which you say it has**)

I can't find a link to back up my theory. [Best I could find -Reading an IS twice-](http://www.coderanch.com/t/277500/Streams/java/Reading-same-InputStream-twice)

Comment: hi i have removed buffered reader, and i got new error for bad token please check i have editted my question. thank you

Comment: @Mayur Look. Don't edit your question. This has been answered. Mark it as answered and post a new question. If anyone has the same error they want to quickly find the answer not separate it out from multiple questions that are personal to you.